# immediately after start byte[] take up a huge amount of memory

Tags: android, memory-leaks

As soon as my app starts, byte arrays take a huge amount of memory:

[image]

I do have ImageViews in my layout, but in the xxhdpi-folder they are about 500k, and I do have two of them.

It also seems that if I navigate back and forth they are never deallocated as the byte array space increases, but the fragment is released (although activity stays the same).

This leads to crashes like

[image]

on Android 4.x

What may be the cause for this?

**EDIT**

I do use layout files with ImageViews; there, the `src` attribute references a PNG in the drawable-folders. E.g. for xxhdpi resolution those files are about 500k, two of that size are used, the other images are much smaller (~ 5 images with ~10-20k).

Comment: Yup, that's byte arrays for you.  I suggest using streams where possible

Comment: ? I'm pretty sure those are the images that are loaded from the xml layout files. Don't get your answer at all.

Comment: It was really more of a comment than an answer.  Without seeing any of your code, I assumed you were working with byte arrays directly.  The comment just pointed out that arrays are a very expensive way of handling bytes. If you're not working with byte arrays; then something appears to have gone rather wrong - but again; more information is probably required

Comment: "in the xxhdpi-folder they are about 500k" -- those are compressed files (PNG, JPEG, etc.). Your heap usage is based on the *uncompressed* `Bitmap` objects that result from reading in those compressed files.

Comment: @CommonsWare is there a good way to reduce the file size for those PNGs?

Comment: @ne1410s okay, sorry. I did an edit, do you need some further information?

Comment: `about 500k` But in memory, they will take up to `x * y * 4`. 4 is R, G, B and A.